What am I measuring regarding the maximum entropy of a sequence of bounded sets converging to an unbounded set?
Let $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be an unbounded Borel set, and $(F_r)_{r\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of bounded sets which has a set theoretic limit of $A$. Also, $\text{dim}_{\text{H}}(\cdot)$ is the Hausdorff dimension while $\mathcal{H}^{\text{dim}_{\text{H}}(\cdot)}(\cdot)$ is the Hausdorff measure in its dimension on the Borel sigma-algebra.
Motivation: I want a "measure" which answers problem 1 and 2 of this post, using this answer to the same post.
After reading section 1. of this post (i.e., "Maximum Entropy"):
Question 1: What am I measuring in section 2?
Question 2: Is there simpler versions of the definitions in section 2?
1. Maximum Entropy
Suppose we define maximum entropy in step 8. (See this mathematica post and $\S$5.4.1 of this paper in case something is unclear.)


For every $r\in\mathbb{N}$, "over-cover" $F_r$ with minimal, pairwise disjoint sets of equal $\mathcal{H}^{\text{dim}_{\text{H}}(F_r)}$ measure. (We denote the equal measures $\varepsilon$, where the former sentence is defined $\mathbf{C}(\varepsilon,F_r,\omega)$: i.e., $\omega\in\Omega_{\varepsilon,r}$ enumerates all collections of these sets covering $F_r$.)
For every $\varepsilon$, $r$ and $\omega$, take a sample point from each set in $\mathbf{C}(\varepsilon,F_r,\omega)$. The set of these points is "the sample" which we define $\mathcal{S}(\mathbf{C}(\varepsilon,F_r,\omega),\psi)$: i.e., $\psi\in\Psi_{\varepsilon,r,\omega}$ enumerates all possible samples of $\mathbf{C}(\varepsilon,F_r,\omega)$

For every $\varepsilon$, $r$, $\omega$ and $\psi$:

Take a “pathway” of line segments: we start with a line segment from arbitrary point $x_0$ of $\mathcal{S}(\mathbf{C}(\varepsilon,F_r,\omega),\psi)$ to the nearest sample point (i.e., when more than one sample point has the same nearness to $x_0$, take either of those points). Next, repeat this process until the “pathway” intersects with every sample point once. (See this post or section 8.3.1 in case of confusion.)
Take the set of the length of all segments in 3., except for lengths that are outliers. Define this $\mathcal{L}(x_0,\mathcal{S}(\mathbf{C}(\varepsilon,F_r,\omega),\psi))$
Multiply remaining lengths in the pathway by a constant so they add up to one (i.e., a probability distribution). This will be denoted $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{L}(x_0,\mathcal{S}(\mathbf{C}(\varepsilon,F_r,\omega),\psi)))$
Take the shannon entropy of step 5. We define this: $$\text{E}(\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{L}(x_0,\mathcal{S}(\mathbf{C}(\varepsilon,F_r,\omega),\psi))))=\sum_{x\in\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{L}(x_0,\mathcal{S}(\mathbf{C}(\varepsilon,F_r,\omega),\psi)))}-x\log_{2}x$$ which will be shortened to $\text{E}(\mathcal{L}(x_0,\mathcal{S}(\mathbf{C}(\varepsilon,F_r,\omega),\psi)))$
Maximize the entropy w.r.t all "pathways". This we will denote:
$$\text{E}(\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{S}(\mathbf{C}(\varepsilon,F_r,\omega),\psi)))=\sup\limits_{x_0\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbf{C}(\varepsilon,F_r,\omega),\psi)}\text{E}(\mathcal{L}(x_0,\mathcal{S}(\mathbf{C}(\varepsilon,F_r,\omega),\psi)))$$
Therefore, the maximum entropy of $(F_r)_{r\in\mathbb{N}}$, using 1. and 2. is:
$$\text{E}_{\text{max}}(F_r)=\sup\limits_{\omega\in\Omega_{\varepsilon,r}}\sup\limits_{\psi\in\Psi_{\varepsilon,r,\omega}}\text{E}(\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{S}(\mathbf{C}(\varepsilon,F_r,\omega),\psi)))$$


2. What Am I Measuring in This Section?
Suppose we define two sequences of bounded sets with a set theoretic limit of $A$: e.g., $(F_r^{\star})_{r\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $(F_j^{\star\star})_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$, where for constant $\varepsilon$ and cardinality $|\cdot|$, we then consider:


Using 2. and 7. of section 1, suppose:

$$\small{\begin{align}  &
 \underline{\left|\mathcal{S}(\mathbf{C}(\varepsilon,F_r^{\star},\omega),\psi)\right|}=\\
 &{\sup\left\{\left|\mathcal{S}(\mathbf{C}(\varepsilon,F_j^{\star\star},\omega^{\prime}),\psi^{\prime})\right|:j\in\mathbb{N},\;
 \omega^{\prime}\in\Omega_{\varepsilon,j} \; \psi^{\prime}\in \Psi_{\varepsilon,j,\omega}, \;
 \text{E}(\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{S}(\mathbf{C}(\varepsilon,F_j^{\star\star},\omega^{\prime}),\psi^{\prime})))
 \le
 \text{E}(\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{S}(\mathbf{C}(\varepsilon,F_r^{\star},\omega),\psi)))\right\}}\nonumber
 \end{align}}$$
$\quad \quad$then (using $\small{\underline{\left|\mathcal{S}(\mathbf{C}(\epsilon,F_r^{\star},\omega),\psi)\right|}}$) we get
$$\small{\begin{equation}
 \overline{\alpha}\left(\varepsilon,r,\omega,\psi\right)=
 \left|\mathcal{S}(\mathbf{C}(\varepsilon,F_r^{\star},\omega),\psi))\right| /\sup\limits_{\omega\in\Omega_{\varepsilon,r}}\sup\limits_{\psi\in\Psi_{\varepsilon,r,\omega}}\underline{\left|\mathcal{S}(\mathbf{C}(\varepsilon,F_r^{\star},\omega),\psi)\right|}
\end{equation}}$$

Also, using 2. and 7. of section 1, suppose:

$$\small{\begin{align}  &
 \overline{\left|\mathcal{S}(\mathbf{C}(\varepsilon,F_r^{\star},\omega),\psi)\right|}=\\ &{\inf\left\{\left|\mathcal{S}(\mathbf{C}(\varepsilon,F_j^{\star\star},\omega^{\prime}),\psi^{\prime})\right|:j\in\mathbb{N},\;
 \omega^{\prime}\in\Omega_{\varepsilon,j} \; \psi^{\prime}\in \Psi_{\varepsilon,j,\omega}, \;
 \text{E}(\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{S}(\mathbf{C}(\varepsilon,F_j^{\star\star},\omega^{\prime}),\psi^{\prime})))
 \ge
 \text{E}(\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{S}(\mathbf{C}(\varepsilon,F_r^{\star},\omega),\psi)))\right\}}\nonumber
 \end{align}}$$
$\quad\quad$ then (using $\small{\overline{\left|\mathcal{S}(\mathbf{C}(\varepsilon,F_r^{\star},\omega),\psi)\right|}}$) we also get:
$$\small{\begin{equation}
 \underline{\alpha}\left(\varepsilon,r,\omega,\psi\right)=
 \left|\mathcal{S}(\mathbf{C}(\varepsilon,F_r^{\star},\omega),\psi))\right|/\sup\limits_{\omega\in\Omega_{\varepsilon,r}}\sup\limits_{\psi\in\Psi_{\varepsilon,r,\omega}}\overline{\left|\mathcal{S}(\mathbf{C}(\varepsilon,F_r^{\star},\omega),\psi)\right|} \end{equation}}$$

If using $\overline{\alpha}\left(\epsilon,r,\omega,\psi\right)$ and $\underline{\alpha}\left(\epsilon,r,\omega,\psi\right)$ we have:

\begin{equation*} \limsup\limits_{\varepsilon\to 0}\limsup\limits_{r\to\infty}\sup\limits_{\omega\in\Omega_{\varepsilon,r}}\sup\limits_{\psi\in\Psi_{\varepsilon,r,\omega}}\overline{\alpha}\left(\varepsilon,r,\omega,\psi\right)=\liminf\limits_{\varepsilon\to 0}\liminf\limits_{r\to\infty}\inf\limits_{\omega\in\Omega_{\varepsilon,r}}\inf\limits_{\psi\in\Psi_{\varepsilon,r,\omega}}\underline{\alpha}\left(\varepsilon,r,\omega,\psi\right)=0 \end{equation*}
$\quad\quad$then what I'm measuring from $(F_r^{\star})_{r\in\mathbb{N}}$ increases at a rate superlinear to that of $(F_j^{\star\star})_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$.

If using equations $\overline{\alpha}\left(\varepsilon,j,\omega,\psi\right)$ and
$\underline{\alpha}\left(\varepsilon,j,\omega,\psi\right)$ (where $r$ and $(F_r^{\star})_{r\in\mathbb{N}}$, in
$\overline{\alpha}\left(\epsilon,r,\omega,\psi\right)$ and
$\underline{\alpha}\left(\epsilon,r,\omega,\psi\right)$, are swapped with $j$ and $(F_j^{\star\star})_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ respectively) we get:

\begin{equation*}\limsup\limits_{\varepsilon\to 0}\limsup\limits_{j\to\infty}\sup\limits_{\omega\in\Omega_{\varepsilon,j}}\sup\limits_{\psi\in\Psi_{\varepsilon,j,\omega}}\overline{\alpha}\left(\varepsilon,j,\omega,\psi\right)=\liminf\limits_{\varepsilon\to 0}\liminf\limits_{j\to\infty}\inf\limits_{\omega\in\Omega_{\varepsilon,j}}\inf\limits_{\psi\in\Psi_{\varepsilon,j,\omega}}\underline{\alpha}\left(\varepsilon,j,\omega,\psi\right)= 0 \end{equation*}
$\quad\quad$then what I'm measuring from $(F_r^{\star})_{r\in\mathbb{N}}$ increases at a rate sublinear to that of $(F_j^{\star\star})_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$.

If using equations $\overline{\alpha}\left(\varepsilon,r,\omega,\psi\right)$, $\underline{\alpha}\left(\varepsilon,r,\omega,\psi\right)$, $\overline{\alpha}\left(\varepsilon,j,\omega,\psi\right)$, and $\underline{\alpha}\left(\varepsilon,j,\omega,\psi\right)$, we both have:

$\limsup\limits_{\varepsilon\to0}\limsup\limits_{r\to\infty}\sup\limits_{\omega\in\Omega_{\varepsilon,r}}\sup\limits_{\psi\in\Psi_{\varepsilon,r,\omega}}\overline{\alpha}\left(\varepsilon,r,\omega,\psi\right)$
or $\liminf\limits_{\varepsilon\to 0}\liminf\limits_{r\to\infty}\inf\limits_{\omega\in\Omega_{\varepsilon,r}}\inf\limits_{\psi\in\Psi_{\varepsilon,r,\omega}}\underline{\alpha}\left(\varepsilon,r,\omega,\psi\right)$ does not equal zero
$\limsup\limits_{\varepsilon\to 0}\limsup\limits_{j\to\infty}\sup\limits_{\omega\in\Omega_{\varepsilon,j}}\sup\limits_{\psi\in\Psi_{\varepsilon,j,\omega}}\overline{\alpha}\left(\varepsilon,j,\omega,\psi\right)$ or $\liminf\limits_{\varepsilon\to 0}\liminf\limits_{j\to\infty}\inf\limits_{\omega\in\Omega_{\varepsilon,j}}\inf\limits_{\psi\in\Psi_{\varepsilon,j,\omega}}\underline{\alpha}\left(\varepsilon,j,\omega,\psi\right)$ does not equal zero



$\quad\quad$then what I'm measuring from $(F_r^{\star})_{r\in\mathbb{N}}$ increases at a rate linear to that of $(F_j^{\star\star})_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$.

Recap of Questions
Question 1: What am I measuring in section 2?
Question 2: Is there simpler versions of the definitions in section 2?
